# How do I get the list of the custom fields added to an entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to get the custom fields created for the *User* entity in Drupal 8.

- `Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldStorageDefinitions('user')` returns all the fields
- `Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('user', '')` returns only the default fields

My code creates the list by removing the fields returned from `getFieldDefinitions('user', '')` by the fields returned from `getFieldDefinitions('user'`.

Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Please, define 'custom fields'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the fields by checking which interface the field implements:

```
$fields = array_filter(
  \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('user', 'user'),
  function ($fieldDefinition) {
    return $fieldDefinition instanceof \Drupal\field\FieldConfigInterface;
  }
);
```

The second parameter of [getFieldDefinitions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManagerInterface.php/function/EntityFieldManagerInterface%3A%3AgetFieldDefinitions/8.7.x) is the bundle. The user entity doesn't have bundles, but you can configure bundle fields. In this case the bundle name defaults to the entity id.